# Send the output of DirectionsRenderer to a textarea

Tags: maps

Can anyone help me sending the output of a DirectionsRenderer object to a textarea

I have tried the code to find driving directions between two places. I have got it working. But, I am looking to display the directions in a text area, which I have on the page.

I have the following code. Please help me.

```
<?php
$s= $_REQUEST['source'].", Pune";
$d= $_REQUEST['destination'].", Pune";

?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>


    <html> 
    <head> 
       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
       <title>Google Maps API v3 Directions Example</title> 
       <script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    </head> 
    <body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;"> 
       <div style="width: 600px;">
         <div id="map" style="width: 280px; height: 400px; float: left;"></div> 
         <div id="panel" style="width: 300px; float: right;"></div> 
   </div>
       <textarea cols="100" rows="10" id="abc"/>
       </textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">     

        var source1 = "<?php echo $s; ?>";
        var dest1 = "<?php echo $d; ?>";
     var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom:7,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
     directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

     var request = {
       origin: source1, 
       destination: dest1,
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
     };

     directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);


       }
     });
   </script> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setPanel after getting the directions.
setPanel writes the directions text to a div.

```
e.g.

  var MapRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            MapRenderer.setMap(map);
            MapRenderer.setDirections(objRoute);
            //Clear the div.
            document.getElementById("oUserPoints").innerHTML = "";
            //Display the route as text in the div.
            MapRenderer.setPanel(oUserPoints);
```

Answer (score -1):

I used a `<div id="content">` to show the result. In the script I replaced this:

```
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
```

with:

```
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('content'));
```

and it worked.